# Error reading a table after using mergeSchema

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I have the option to merge schema enabled:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled","true")
```

I created this dataframe:

```
data = [("data0",10,"2023-06-26 08:16:18.036", 18.5),
        ("data1",24,"2023-06-26 01:19:18.036", 1.5),
        ("data2",25,"2023-06-26 09:20:18.036", 18.5)]
schema = StructType([StructField("col1",StringType(),True),
                     StructField("col2",IntegerType(),True),
                     StructField("col3",StringType(),True),
                     StructField("col4",FloatType(),True)])

df_mirror = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
df_mirror = df_mirror.withColumn("col3",col("col3").cast("timestamp"))
```

Then I created the table **landing_2** like this:

```
df_landing = df_mirror.withColumn("ins", lit("NOMDB"))\
        .withColumn("insert_date", current_timestamp() - expr("INTERVAL 24 HOURS") )\
        .withColumn("update_date",current_timestamp() - expr("INTERVAL 24 HOURS"))
df_landing.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("schema_test.landing2")
#the df_landing
+-----+----+-----------------------+----+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|col1 |col2|col3                   |col4|ins     |insert_date            |update_date            |
+-----+----+-----------------------+----+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|data0|10  |2023-06-26 08:16:18.036|18.5|NOMDB   |2023-07-05 20:53:03.526|2023-07-05 20:53:03.526|
|data1|24  |2023-06-26 01:19:18.036|1.5 |NOMDB   |2023-07-05 20:53:03.526|2023-07-05 20:53:03.526|
|data2|25  |2023-06-26 09:20:18.036|18.5|NOMDB   |2023-07-05 20:53:03.526|2023-07-05 20:53:03.526|
+-----+----+-----------------------+----+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

After I created another dataframe:

```
+-----+----+-----------------------+----+----+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|col1 |col2|col3                   |col4|col5|ins     |insert_date            |update_date            |
+-----+----+-----------------------+----+----+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|data8|10  |2023-06-26 08:16:18.036|18.5|null|NOMDB   |2023-07-05 20:56:16.891|2023-07-05 20:56:16.891|
+-----+----+-----------------------+----+----+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

Then I executed this:

```
df_landing.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("schema_test.landing2")
```

I didn't get any error, but when I try to read the table with SQL like this:

```
%sql
SELECT * FROM schema_test.landing2
```

I get the next error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't find col5#25652 in [col1#25645,col2#25646,col3#25647,col4#25648,instance#25649,insert_date#25650,update_date#25651]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is due to a mismatch between the schema of the new dataframe you're trying to append and the schema of the table landing2. Your landing2 table has the columns col1, col2, col3, col4, ins, insert_date, update_date and does not have the col5 column which exists in your new dataframe.

The saveAsTable operation doesn't perform schema validation on the dataframe that's being written in append mode. It simply appends the rows from your dataframe to the existing table. The fact that your dataframe has an additional column col5 does not cause any issues during the write operation.

However, when you try to read the table, the underlying engine tries to reconcile the data from the new rows with the schema of the existing table. At this point, it encounters a column (col5) in the new rows that doesn't exist in the table schema, causing the error you're seeing.

In other words, the error occurs when reading the data, not when writing it.

Just add col5 to your table landing2:

```
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE schema_test.landing2 ADD COLUMNS (col5 INT)")
```

Comment: Hi @Vector I fixed changing the `null` value to another like `"foo"` and now I don't get that error, but thanks for the answer